# Pegar os registros da semana corrente

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um sistema onde o usuário cadastra as informações em uma base de dados Mysql. Um dos campos é **DataCadastro** do tipo **Date()** e que é cadastrado apenas de segunda a sexta, ou seja, nos dias que a empresa desse usuário funciona. Preciso pegar apenas os registros da semana corrente. Entendo que para pegar os próximos 7 dias, tenho que fazer isso:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dataCadastro BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Mas como eu faria para pegar somente as datas da semana corrente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução 1:

Como é MySQL, você pode utilizar a função [YEARWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek), basta você colocar a data dentro da função `YEARWEEK('2018-07-24')`

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Solução 2:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Comment: Perfeito fabionvs. A primeira solução caiu melhor na minha aplicação. Muito obrigado!